# Is it possible to upgrade original iMac (1998) memory (RAM) to above 256 MB?

Tags: imac, memory

I am looking into buying myself an original iMac, and I want to mess with the older system a little bit.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G3

[image: iMac G3 image from Wikipedia]

Also, is it even remotely possible to change the RAM in the system to being over 256 MB. I am willing to do it even if it means changing out other parts to allow it to be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple reports that this model can support a maximum of 128 MB of RAM. However, the "revision A" model "unofficially" can support a maximum of 384 MB of memory (one 128 MB and one 256 MB module) and the "revision B" model can use a maximum of 512 MB of memory (two 256 MB modules).

Answer (score 5):

The [maximum amount of RAM](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac_ab.html) that the iMac G3 could accept was 384MB for the Rev. A model and 512MB of RAM for the Rev. B model.

This was done with a 128MB and a 256MB module or two 256MB modules of 144pin PC66 RAM, respectively.